# Razor rendering error

Tags: razor, servicestack

I'm trying to troubleshoot a Razor rendering error. I've tried recreating the project from scratch. Any ideas what might cause this?

```
error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 
'ServiceStack.Razor.RenderingPage.WriteTo(System.IO.TextWriter, 
ServiceStack.MiniProfiler.HelperResult)' has some invalid arguments
```

**Stack Trace**

```
at ServiceStack.Razor.Compilation.RazorPageHost.Compile() at 
ServiceStack.Razor.Managers.RazorPageResolver.EnsureCompiled(RazorPage page, IHttpResponse response) at 
ServiceStack.Razor.Managers.RazorPageResolver.CreateRazorPageInstance(IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes, Object dto, RazorPage razorPage) at 
ServiceStack.Razor.Managers.RazorPageResolver.ResolveAndExecuteRazorPage(IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes, Object model, RazorPage razorPage) at 
ServiceStack.Razor.Managers.RazorPageResolver.ProcessRequest(IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes, Object dto) at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Formats.HtmlFormat.c__DisplayClass1.b__0(IViewEngine x) at 
System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) at 
ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Formats.HtmlFormat.SerializeToStream(IRequestContext requestContext, Object response, IHttpResponse httpRes) at 
ServiceStack.Common.Web.HttpResponseFilter.SerializeToStream(IRequestContext requestContext, Object response, Stream responseStream) at 
ServiceStack.Common.Web.HttpResult.WriteTo(Stream responseStream) at 
ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Extensions.HttpResponseExtensions.WriteToOutputStream(IHttpResponse response, Object result, Byte[] bodyPrefix, Byte[] bodySuffix) at 
ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Extensions.HttpResponseExtensions.WriteToResponse(IHttpResponse response, Object result, ResponseSerializerDelegate defaultAction, IRequestContext serializerCtx, Byte[] bodyPrefix, Byte[] bodySuffix)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just gotten the same error myself and have come to the conclusion that ServiceStack doesn't support razor @helpers correctly (at least that's where my error came from). If I can get some time I'll add that feature.